# Thymeleaf Using th:if within a th:block

Tags: html, boolean, each, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and am trying to create an html table where a boolean decides whether the text will be pass or fail in some of the columns.

SmokeTest.passOrFailArray is an array of booleans.
Right now the smokeTest.name is showing up in the column but the passed or failed text is not showing up at all.

Here is my thymeleaf/html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Smoke Tests</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<tr>
    <td>Test Name</td>
    <td th:each="testsThatRan : ${testsThatRan}"
    th:text="${testsThatRan}">Tests</td>
</tr>
<th:block th:each="smokeTest : ${smokeTests}">
<tr>
   <td th:text="${smokeTest.name}">A Smoke Test'</td>
   <th:block th:each="smokeTest.passOrFailArray : ${smokeTest.passOrFailArray}">
        <td th:if="${smokeTest.passOrFailArray} == true" th:text="Passed"></td>
        <td th:if="${smokeTest.passOrFailArray} == false" th:text="failed"></td>

   </th:block>
</tr>
</th:block>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the class that im using as a variable in thymeleaf

```
public testers() throws IOException {

    localPath = "/Users/dansbacher14/Documents/workspace/OBI_nightly_test/src/OBI_ci_scripts_tests";
    remotePath = "ssh://git@stash.ops.aol.com:2022/obi/obi_ci_scripts.git";
    localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath + "/.git");
    pathToSmoke = "BPS/GPS/GATHR/SMOKE";
    pathToODirectory = "test-results";
    git = new Git(localRepo);
}

public static <C> void testClone() throws IOException, InvalidRemoteException, TransportException, GitAPIException 
{

    Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remotePath).setDirectory(new File(localPath)).call();
}


//____________SETTERS AND GETTERS __________________________________________________________________________________

public void setName(String name)
{
    jmxName = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return jmxName;
}


public boolean[] getPassOrFailArray()
{
    return passOrFailArray;
}

public String getLocalPath()
{
    return localPath;
}
```

}

This is how the source code is presented by the browser.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Smoke Tests</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<tr>
    <td>Test Name</td>
    <td>OBI01</td>
    <td>DEV</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>authAmtTesting.jmx</td>



</tr>


<tr>
   <td>authTesting.jmx</td>




</tr>


<tr>
   <td>CC_Crypto.jmx</td>





</tr>


<tr>
   <td>ci_address.jmx</td>


</tr>


<tr>
   <td>ci_cardtype_negative.jmx</td>



</tr>


<tr>
   <td>ci_cardtype_positive.jmx</td>


</tr>


<tr>
   <td>promoSmokeTst.jmx</td>



</tr>


<tr>
   <td>tokenizedPayment.jmx</td>


</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do something like this in thymeleaf?  If so how could I make this work?  Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the HTML that is being rendered in the browser?

Comment: Also could you post the classes you are using because it's not exactly clear from the Thymeleaf code what the model is actually like

Answer (score 6):

This code works

```
<th:block th:each="pf : ${smokeTest.passOrFailArray}">
        <td th:if="${pf} == true" th:text="Passed"></td>
        <td th:if="${pf} == false" th:text="failed"></td>

   </th:block>
```

the problem is that i was naming my variable in the each loop incorrectly.  The name cannot have a period in it.